# Selecting data from other table using a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying to get the clan tag from ranks table for a specific member_id. But I don't understand how to do that. I used INNER JOIN commands but nothing works.

```
CREATE TABLE ranks(
    rank VARCHAR(8),
    tag VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(rank)
    );

CREATE TABLE member(
    member_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(15),
    ign VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    rank VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    joined_date DATE NOT NULL,
    dob DATE,
    sex ENUM('M','F') NOT NULL,
    country VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(member_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(rank) REFERENCES ranks(rank)
    );

INSERT INTO ranks VALUES
    ('Founder','|NoMercy|King'),
    ('Admin','^1|NoMercy|^7'),
    ('TmpAdmin','^5|NoMercy|^7'),
    ('Pro','^1|NoMercy PRO|^7'),
    ('Member','^4|NoMercy|^7'),
    ('Banned','BANNED');

INSERT INTO member VALUES
    (NULL,'Reznov','NULL','REZ','Member','2017/12/22','1954/02/28','M','RUS'),
    (NULL,'Amanda','NULL','S3XXY|G!RL|','Pro','2018/01/05','1992/01/25','F','USA'),
    (NULL,'Elmasri','Navathe','INDIAN_Noob _XOX','TmpAdmin','2018/04/02','1960/08/25','M','IND'),
    (NULL,'Tony','Silva','Cool KiD','Member','2018/04/26','1988/02/22','M','BR'),
    (NULL,'Hashan','NULL','Big Papa','Member','2018/05/08','1996/06/12','M','NZ'),
    (NULL,'Emma','Watson','EmmaXXX','Banned','2018/06/10','1985/05/22','F','UK');
```

I need to output the correct tag for specific member. It should only display the tag.

Please help!

Comment: Can you please share what you tried?

Comment: SELECT tag FROM member
INNER JOIN ranks ON member.rank = ranks.rank;

SELECT tag FROM ranks,member WHERE member_id=1;

Comment: Add sample data and expected output.

Comment: I updated the original post.

Comment: @SheharaDinuwan check answer please

Comment: @SheharaDinuwan Your query `SELECT tag FROM member INNER JOIN ranks ON member.rank = ranks.rank` should work fine. Just add the required `Where` condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below query should be worked

```
SELECT tag FROM ranks INNER JOIN member  ON ranks.rank=member.rank 
      where member_id=1;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e90392/1

```
    tag
^4|NoMercy|^7
```